# failing to cross the pons asinorum with jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

OK, well, this has got to be something really dumb.

I've got a little JSP app. I want to add a date picker. I downloaded the jQuery UI bundle. If I point chrome at the index.html that it gives me as a demo, all is well. When I move the pieces into my webapp, not so good.

The chrome console shows two things:

1. Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
2. Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'datepicker'

Obviously, the second is where the headache arrives. I do have a <div id='calendar'>.

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/harvest.css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Data Collection</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                // Datepicker
                $('#calendar').datepicker({
                    inline: true, altField: 'input#date', altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
```

Comment: maybe I missed something obvious, but what does Euclid's theorem on isosceles triangles (pons asinorum) have anything to do with this situation?

Comment: @Thr it's called the pons assinorum because it's the first and easiest bridge to cross. If you can't understand that, you're not going to understand *anything*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I figured it out. (I'm pretty certain)

you have a script loading from `/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js`, but when I dl a ui bundle, it downloads a file `js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js`. Notice that the second one has a *2* in it. When I did that, everything worked again for me.

Here are the following basics that I can think of:

- what happens when you directly go to `/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` and `/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custum.min.js` ?  If those don't work then obviously you have a wrong pathname.
- have you downloaded a jquery ui package before? perhaps the index.html page you are viewing is not associated with the ui package you dl'ed but with a differently downloaded ui package (which may indicate that you simply forgot to check the datepicker box when dl'ing it this latest time)
- is there some page that's cached in Chrome? does deleteing all cache help?
- what happens when you try it in FF, IE, or Safari?

Comment: Sure enough. Dislexics of the world untie. Now all I have to do is shrink it from size 12 to some reasonable size.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for getting this error is when you make the call with the wrong case like this:
$("#calendar").date**P**icker() 
instead of 
$("#calendar").datepicker()

I have struggled to find this error for a few hours.